# I'm not sure how to specify an element by their class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, clone

I currently have a table with two rows, and my Javascript is intended to work as when a cell in the table is clicked the entire row's element disappears and the clicked cell gets cloned to the leftmost position, and a slider will open up on the right side of the cloned cell. However, when I try to do the function of closing the slider I have no idea how to specify which slider to close, therefore often times if I have both of the sliders in the two rows open up the wrong one will get closed. I'm trying to add a class for the cloned element and a class for the slider defining which row each of them are in and therefore specify which one to close but I'm not sure how I can specify the slider to close by their class.

HTML:

```
<table id='TrendGames'>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="cell1" class='Row1'>
                <img class='GameCover' src='Fortnite Front Cover.png' alt="cell1" />
                </td>
                <td id="cell2">
                <img class='GameCover' src='LOL Front Cover.png' alt="cell2" />
                </td>
                <td id="cell3">
                <img class='GameCover' src='Minecraft Front Cover.png' alt="cell3" />
                </td>
                <td id="cell4">
                <img class='GameCover' src='Roblox Front Cover.png' alt="cell4" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="cell5" class='Row2'>
                <img class='GameCover' src='Call of Duty Front Cover.jpg' alt="cell5" />
                </td>
                <td id="cell6">
                <img class='GameCover' src='Valorant Front Cover.jpg' alt="cell6" />
                </td>
                <td id="cell7">
                <img class='GameCover' src='Counter Strike 2 Front Cover.jpeg' alt="cell7" />
                </td>
                <td id="cell8">
                <img class='GameCover' src='The Sim 4 Front Cover.webp' alt="cell8" />
                </td>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let table = document.getElementById('TrendGames');
  table.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    let clickedCell = event.target.closest('td');
    if (clickedCell) {
      handleCellClick(clickedCell);
    }
  });
});

function handleCellClick(clickedCell) {
  const row = clickedCell.parentElement;
  const cells = row.children;
  const display = cells[cells.length - 1].style.display ? '' : 'none';

  for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].style.display = display;
  }
  if (display) { 
    const newCell = clickedCell.cloneNode(true);
    newCell.style.display = '';
    newCell.colSpan = cells.length;
    row.insertBefore(newCell, row.firstChild);
    openSlider(newCell);
  } else {
    clickedCell.remove();
    closeSlider(clickedCell);
  }
}
    
function openSlider(cell) {
  let WhichSlider = cell.id; // Using cell.id instead of clickedCell.ID
  switch(WhichSlider) {
    case "cell1":
        slider1(cell)
        break;
    case "cell2":
        slider2(cell)
        break;
    case "cell3":
        slider3(cell)
        break;
    case "cell4":
        slider4(cell)
        break;
    case "cell5":
        slider5(cell)
        break;
    case "cell6":
        slider6(cell)
        break;
    case "cell7":
        slider7(cell)
        break;
    case "cell8":
        slider8(cell)
        break;
  }
}

// down here are the functions of the open slider (slider1-slider8)

function closeSlider(cell) {
let slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
if (slider) {
    slider.remove();
}
}
```

Comment: [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the class attribute of an element with [the `className` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className).

So in your particular case you could do `cells[0].className` in `handleCellClick` to get the class attribute’s value.

Comment: I just figured out that I needed a globally scoped variable to use it in the closeSlider block but it works thanks.